# Short story where Hitler tries to escape via time travel, only to end up being becoming the man killed in his bunker days prior

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, time-travel

I'm looking for a science fiction short story. I think I read it in the 90s — no idea whether it was a magazine or anthology.

In the last days of Hitler, his guards find a disheveled and incoherent man in a secure area near Hitler's living quarters.  I think they execute him — or perhaps keep him (or his dead body) as a decoy in case one is needed.  A few days later, the war is going badly enough that Hitler uses the experimental time machine the Germans have developed to try to escape (against perhaps intending that the other guy will be captured instead).  The time travel process leaves Adolf confused and disheveled — and drops him off a few days in the past, in his own bunker, where he's captured by guards.

Comment: @DavidW Oh, I doubt it's 30% -- I've read a lot of time travel stories, and I'm fairly sure no more than one in six involved Hitler in any way.  Probably fewer than 10% of the *good* ones...

Comment: Thanks for the helpful edits!

Comment: Must post this: https://xkcd.com/1063/